# Web design from template

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web designing.
I started to designing a sample page but I have some challenges.

I have photoshop template like below image.
to convert it to HTML and CSS I fallowed these steps :

- I separated background image with logo then I putted to background of body
- I created main DIV as page container with relative position.
- now I want to put texts to page ( OH BOY WE'RE LOST !) and ( THE RESOURCE YOU ARE LOOKING FOR MIGHT HAVE BEEN REMOVED, HAD ITS NAME CHANGED OR
                  TEMPORARILY UNAVAILABLE.)
  I have some questions here :
- How do I put them on Page ? both of them in one DIV ? or each one in separated DIV ?
- How should I position them to having same position in picture and web site ? is there any specific technique exist ? or should I do i with test and try ?

Please explain me.
[image: Mentioned Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the width `width:100%` of the page div. and give `<h1>` tag for `"OH BOY WE'RE LOST!"` with  specified width and margin: 0 auto;.

and `<p>` tag for remaining text that `"HE RESOURCE YOU ARE LOOKING FOR MIGHT HAVE BEEN REMOVED, HAD ITS NAME CHANGED OR TEMPORARILY UNAVAILABLE."`

```
<div class="page">
<h1>OH BOY WE'RE LOST!</h1>
<p>HE RESOURCE YOU ARE LOOKING FOR MIGHT HAVE BEEN REMOVED, HAD ITS NAME CHANGED OR TEMPORARILY UNAVAILABLE.</p>
</div>
```

css :

```
.page {
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
.page h1 {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
font-size: /*your font size*/
font-family: /*your font family*/
width:100px; /*you can change the width as per your need*/
margin:0 auto;
}
.page p {
width:98%;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
How do I position Left and Top of .Page h1 and .Page p ?
how can i find right Top and Left ?
Is there any way to find from PSD template ?

Comment: i have edited the answer, no need to give position for page p. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> How do I put them on Page ? both of them in one DIV ? or each one in separated DIV ?

Both of them in seperate div and enclosing them in the background image `div`. I personally prefer `span` than `div` because it is plain text.

```
<div class="backGroundImag">
    <span class="text1"> Text goes here </span>
    <span class="text2"> Text goes here </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.
I have problem when I want to positioning text1 and text2 (I mean in your sample code).
Can I find right position from PSD template ? What top and left should I set?

Comment: @shaahin -  Yes, that is the way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to keep in mind the web is not a pixel perfect medium** as there are so many variables in play: different browsers, operating systems, screen resolutions etc.

If you are new to web designing, start with something a little more simple. What you have there is a great design that may not immediately translate easily to the web (your search box for a start would provide some interesting implementation challenges).

Don't aim too high early on. Read, practice, repeat. Here is a good article on centered design techniques to get you started: 
http://www.webdesignforidiots.net/2009/03/fixed-width-centered-website/

Marked as CW because this is advice and not an answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
body { margin:0px; padding:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.wrapper { width:600px; margin:0px auto; background:url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat; min-height:437px; }
.header { width:144px; margin:0px auto; padding: 25px 0 20px 0; height:130px; } /*If you want logo Seperatly use this step*/
.header h1 { margin:0px; padding:0px; } /*For Seo prupose*/
.content { margin:0px auto; padding:0px; width:480px; }
.content h1 { text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:16px; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.content h2 { font-size:12px; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header"><h1><!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />-->Logo</h1></div>
<div class="content">
<h1>OH BOY WE'RE LOST !</h1>
<h2>THE RESOURCE YOU ARE LOOKING FOR MIGHT HAVE BEEN REMOVED, HAD ITS NAME CHANGED OR TEMPORARILY UNAVAILABLE.</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to place the logo separately, that's the good practice. then margin:0px auto; it helps to align the page as center, but you have to mention width according to your page size.